# replace user control in grid

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, user-controls

My xaml looks like this:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        ...
    <Grid>
    ...
    <Grid Grid.Row="3">
        <local:UserControl1 Visibility = "{Binding UserControl1Visibility}" />
        <local:UserControl2 Visibility = "{Binding UserControl2Visibility}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Control1Visibility and Control2Visibility are properties in my ViewModel, but it isn't work. This grid couldn't dynamically display the two user control. Anyone has ideas?

Edit

VM:

```
private Visibility userControl1Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

        public Visibility UserControl1Visibility
        {
            get { return userControl1Visibility; }
            set
            {
                if (userControl1Visibility != value)
                {
                    userControl1Visibility = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("UserControl1Visibility");
                }
            }
        }


        private Visibility userControl2Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;

        public Visibility UserControl2Visibility
        {
            get { return userControl2Visibility ; }
            set
            {
                if (userControl2Visibility != value)
                {
                    userControl2Visibility = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("UserControl2Visibility");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: what's not working?  Are you seeing either of the controls initially? Could you post your ViewModel code as well?

Comment: can you share your VM code? and how u r setting the DataContext for your view?

Comment: @Andrew,@nit, I have attached my viewmodel, when the application run, usercontrol1 couldn't display. I have a button to switch their visibility, but doesn't work.

Comment: nit asked a good question - how do you set the DataContext on your grid?

Comment: In my View's code behind: this.DataContext = MainViewModel.Instance;

Answer (score 1):

You have the names wrong - in the xaml you call them Control1Visibility and Control2Visibility, but in the ViewModel, you are calling them UserControl1Visibility and UserControl2Visibility.  Change the names in one or the other, and make sure the PropertyChanged events are raised with the appropriate string.

Comment: Also for Usercontrol1 you are returning advancedSearchViewVisibility while setting userControl1...

Comment: Sorry @Andrew and nit, I input wrong code, the names are correct, please see my editted code.

Comment: still your xaml shows Control1Visibility and Control2Visibility. Also can you check if output window is reporting any binding errors?

Comment: :( binding has no errors, ok, wrong again! The Binding in xaml has the same name with the properties in viewmodel

Comment: ok.. one more question? how are you updating the property values and Is UserControl2  collapsed intially when you show ur view?

Comment: When the View shows first time, usercontrol1 should display, but it doesn't. I have a button on the view, when user click the button, set the current control as collapsed and the other as visible.

Comment: Since it seems like this is part of a larger application (with at least 4 rows in the Grid) - have you tried isolating the issue by cutting out the other code and just focusing on the problematic part?  It could be a number of things - like you're never showing the Grid at all or that some ViewModel is not getting created etc etc